# Grails 4 Controllers: Where in Grails 4 code can I find a proof that grails.controllers.defaultScope = 'singleton'

Tags: grails

From various searches

- https://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Controllers/scope.html
- http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Default-scope-for-controllers-doc-td4657986.html

I understand the default Controllers scope changed from 'prototype' to 'singleton', perhaps a long time ago. I want to understand in which version exactly the change happened.

But as I should only ask one question, I am asking:

Where in Grails 4 code can I find a proof that grails.controllers.defaultScope = 'singleton'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the key for that setting - https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/948bf681ece30322e7bd5e63bf734fbf0ce68ec0/grails-core/src/main/groovy/grails/config/Settings.groovy#L109

Here is a test that the setting works - https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/7ab9e47ad805fbeb9433a488dd33f91bef44c0fa/grails-core/src/test/groovy/org/grails/core/DefaultGrailsControllerClassSpec.groovy#L15-L25

And here is where it is actually set - though it does seem that if it is unset in config it would be prototype, (which... is odd) - https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/7ab9e47ad805fbeb9433a488dd33f91bef44c0fa/grails-core/src/main/groovy/org/grails/core/DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java#L80

Comment: I've opened a PR to make the unset value the same as the default value https://github.com/grails/grails-core/pull/11592

Comment: This answered my question both in letter and in spirit exactly, so I will accept, but let me ask a confirmation follow-up: Is it correct, that, if nowhere in my Grails 4 application configuration I set "grails.controllers.defaultScope", and my controller is  simple like this: "class MyTestController { def index() {} }", then MyTestController will be prototype? Thanks

Comment: Correct, before my PR that was the (odd) behavior https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/7ab9e47ad805fbeb9433a488dd33f91bef44c0fa/grails-core/src/main/groovy/org/grails/core/DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java#L80

Comment: Unfortunately my change to make it the actual default was rejected. You will need the key in your config or scope defined in a controller to have the desired behavior.

Comment: Actually, I do like that the behaviour stays as is. I just spent  2 months converting a large application from Grails 2.0 to Grails 4.0.1, and I definitely like the defaults not  changing on me (some did). If it was "prototype" before by convention, I like it to stay that way forever :) - in addition, it would be dangerous security wise I think (if the default changed to singleton) . Great and useful answer, accepting it now.